# What's the difference between ActivityCompat and ContextCompat?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I'm trying to use the Android camera, for API 23 or above, it requires asking for permission at runtime. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions#verify_permissions_before_calling_apis), I can accomplish that using, ActivityCompat or ContextCompat. I don't understand what are the difference between the two and their trade-offs.

Thank you for time.

Comment: ActivityCompat extends ContextCompat

Comment: Addition useful info [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en). Clear and short.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I don't understand what are the difference between the two and their trade-offs

There's no trade-off really. Not sure why they wrote so - [checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) is a method of `ContextCompat` and `ActivityCompat` is subclass (child) of `ContextCompat` so you can pass either one whenever object of `ContextCompat` class is required.

Inheritance hierarchy ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marcin! You answered my question. I didn't know that ActivityCompat was a direct child of ContextCompat.

Comment: Glad it helped. But you can always check class hierarchy in documentation of each class, i.e. check [ActivityCompat docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) and you see (on top) that it extends `ContextCompat` which extends `Object`.

Comment: I had the same question, and I think this answer could add a very brief note on why ContextCompat and ActivityCompat is used differently in all samples out there, as that is what is causing this confusion in the first place.