# Android : getDrawable and other resources without a version check?

Tags: java, android

I have to do these kind of checks pretty often in my code and i wanted to know if there is a clean way of getting resources without having to write if statements to check for versions.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
{
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_circled_v));
}
else
{
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_circled_v));
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087128/when-to-use-contextcompact-class

Comment: Good explanation here about the various compat options. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/4138919

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can obtain your drawable resource and maintain backward compatibility.

This is the code you want to use in your Activity:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon_heart_fill_red));
```

where **icon_heart_fill_red** is the name of your drawable.

Answer (score 1):

use annotations, @requireApi or @targetApi